# Can't get Apache2 working

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, httpd, apache-2.2

I had installed Apache2 before, and now when I tried running it again, it doesn't.
My Apache2 settings are:

```
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:/var/run$ apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov 18 2010 21:17:19
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

When I do this, the following errors come up:

```
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:/var/run$ httpd status
No command 'httpd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dhttpd' from package 'dhttpd' (universe)
 Command 'xttpd' from package 'xtide' (universe)
 Command 'thttpd' from package 'thttpd' (universe)
httpd: command not found
```

My `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` looks like:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

#NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

#<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
#    Listen 443
#</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
#    Listen 443
#</IfModule>
```

My `sites-available` directory has these two files:

```
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:/etc/apache2$ cd sites-available/
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
default  default-ssl
```

When I look into `sites-enabled` directory, it has nothing:

```
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cd ../sites-enabled/
jatin@jatin-ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls
```

My /var/log/apache2/error.log file shows this:

```
[Sat Mar 26 17:54:08 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /htdocs
[Sat Mar 26 17:54:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /htdocs
[Sat Mar 26 17:54:23 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 26 17:54:26 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I read on Web that this has got to do something with the Server root not properly set and therefore it looks for the /htdocs folder.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Why does the `httpd status` doesn't show anything??
2. Is everything in my `ports.conf` file correct?? I have just one line uncommented for the `Listen`.
3. Aren't there supposed to be sym links for the default in the sites-enabled directory???
4. When I do `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart/stop/start` everything works fine, but nothing shows up when I open `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost:80/` or `http://localhost:8080/`???
5. What is this thing with Server Root and have i set it correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Why does the httpd status doesn't show anything?**

Because you do not have `httpd` installed. Perhaps you meant `/etc/init.d/httpd status`? The equivalent command on an Ubuntu system is `/etc/init.d/apache2 status`.

- **Is everything in my ports.conf file correct?**

If you are only going to run one site then it should be ok. If you want to have more sites running as virtualhosts you will need to uncomment the `NameVirtualHost` line too.

- **Aren't there supposed to be sym links for the default in the sites-enabled directory?**

They are created when you use the [a2ensite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/a2ensite.8.html) command to enable a site e.g.

```
a2ensite default
```

will enable the default website by creating the link.

- **When I do `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart/stop/start` everything works fine...**

Looking at the error messages in your question, they would indicate that you are not seeing nothing. You will be seeing a 404 Not Found error message. This is caused because you do not have any sites enabled.

- **What is this thing with Server Root and have I set it correct**

I suspect that you mean [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot), if there is no DocumentRoot configured then Apache defaults to /htdocs. Enable a site using the command above and see what happens. You should get a message saying something like "**It Works** ..."

Comment: Thanks. `a2ensite default` worked. Can you guide me to a article on how to use virtual hosts using Apache.

Comment: @Jatin: http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-part-1

Answer (score 1):

I remember some service awhile back complained and said "hey this won't work in the future - you should use service something stop/start/restart"
I thought it was apache but when I ran:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It didn't give that warning message today, but I think you can also do

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I would check /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and make sure the document root is set to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Did you install Apache using tasksel or during install?

Comment: I checked `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and yes the `Document Root` is set to `/var/www`. I don't remember if I installed apache using tasksel, i guess i didn't, anyways would it make a difference?